# Bought a bitcoin, sender said it was sent, not showing in blockchain or wallet. Where is it?

Tags: transactions, wallet, blockchain, fraud

So I bought a full btc off of localbitcoin with amazon giftcard code. 
I sent the code and clicked that payment was completed. 
It's been about 2 hours. About 1 hour since he said that he sent the btc. I'm wondering if I got ripped off? 
I'm not showing any transaction in the block chain and it's definitely not in my wallet. 
Please help? What's going on?

Comment: I agree with Wizards answer.I as well have never had a problem with Local Bitcoins but escrow is there to protect you.Never release funds until you recieve your BTC.

Answer (score 2):

LocalBitcoins uses escrow. If you've released payment and not received the Bitcoin all you need to raise a dispute. If you've already finalised the purchase and the Bitcoin isn't in your LocalBitcoins wallet then there's very little that can be done.

To clarify: did the Bitcoin ever get credited to your LocalBitcoins wallet? If not, raise a dispute ASAP.

I've never had issues with LocalBitcoins but I've never ventured outside of escrow or used gift cards.